# Running move_base with gmapping

Tags: ros, navigation, gmapping, laser-scan-matcher, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I went though all relevantly tagged questions here and some tutorials, but still can't figure out what's wrong with my setup. As in subject, I'd like to configure move_base to work with `gmapping` on-line - `gmapping` is configured correctly, hence running. My config is mostly as described in [Navigation Setup Wiki-post](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup), ie.:

**`costmap_common_params.yaml`**:

```
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
robot_radius: 0.5
inflation_radius: 0.55

observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: /laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

**`global_costmap_params.yaml`**:

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  static_map: false
```

**`local_costmap_params.yaml`**:

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: world
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  resolution: 0.05
```

**`base_local_planner_params.yaml`**:

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:

  max_vel_x: 0.1 #m/s
  min_vel_x: 0.0
  escape_vel: -0.1
  max_rotational_vel: 0.1 #rad/s
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.0

  y_vels: [-0.1, -0.0, 0.0, 0.1]

  acc_lim_th: 1.0
  acc_lim_x: 1.0 #m/s2
  acc_lim_y: 1.0

  holonomic_robot: true
```

**`move_base.launch`**:

```
<launch>
  <master auto="start"/>

  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot)/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot)/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot)/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

I launch laser-scan based `gmapping` before and it's all functional. I selected `\world` as odom frame in all `gmapping` packages, so I repeated this in `move_base` as well, hope this shouldn't be a problem. In rviz I selected **`move_base_simple`** in Tool properties -> 2D Nav Goal -> Topic. Yet, when I define a goal, nothing gets published on **`/cmd_vel`** topic.

What else do I need? Any hints appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12366/running-move_base-with-gmapping/) by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1079 on 2011-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
You should set the goal topic to "move_base_simple/goal", not just "move_base_simple". Or was that just a typo? IIRC there are several other goal topics also, at least in my setup. You could try them too.

You can also use the command "rxgraph" to make sure that all the nodes are correctly connected, so there isn't a gap somewhere. Can be kind of hard if there are several package internal nodes and you don't really know which topics should be forwarded where, though...

---

Originally posted by [raahlb](https://answers.ros.org/users/966/raahlb/) with karma: 317 on 2011-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-12-15**:
Nope, not a typo :)